# Jazzy OSX 10.11.3 Xcode 7.2.1 Issue Finding XCRUN

Tags: macos, xcode7.2, jazzy

with the following command line, have the following issue with Jazzy.  have checked the command line tools, etc, all looks good.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ whereis xcrun
/usr/bin/xcrun
```

shell command / script

```
jazzy \
--clean \
--author Realm \
--author_url https://realm.io \
--github_url https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa \
--github-file-prefix https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/v0.96.2 \
--module-version 0.96.2 \
--xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,RealmSwift \
--module RealmSwift \
--root-url https://realm.io/docs/swift/0.96.2/api/ \
--output docs/swift_output \
--theme docs/themesJeffs-MBP-2:smallSDKSwift jefforthober$ jazzy \
>   --clean \
>   --author Realm \
>   --author_url https://realm.io \
>   --github_url https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa \
>   --github-file-prefix https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/v0.96.2 \
>   --module-version 0.96.2 \
>   --xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,RealmSwift \
>   --module RealmSwift \
>   --root-url https://realm.io/docs/swift/0.96.2/api/ \
>   --output docs/swift_output \
>   --theme docs/themes
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcrun", not a developer tool or in PATH
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:211:in `spawn': No such file or directory -  (Errno::ENOENT)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:211:in `popen_run'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:99:in `popen3'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:279:in `capture3'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:86:in `xcrun'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:119:in `swift_info'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:57:in `swift_version'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:53:in `block in find_swift_version'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:44:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:44:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:53:in `select'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcinvoke-0.2.1/lib/xcinvoke/xcode.rb:53:in `find_swift_version'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.5.0/lib/jazzy/sourcekitten.rb:136:in `run_sourcekitten'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.5.0/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:57:in `block in build'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.5.0/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:55:in `chdir'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.5.0/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:55:in `build'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.5.0/bin/jazzy:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/jazzy:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/jazzy:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Looks like this was the problem.  > 1 version of xcode installed.  XCODE / PREFERENES / LOCATIONS / COMMAND LINE TOOLS.  Selected the proper one, it was blank when not working even after installed a new version of the tools.

Comment: You should move this to an answer to be obvious that this is the fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was the problem. > 1 version of xcode installed. XCODE / PREFERENES / LOCATIONS / COMMAND LINE TOOLS. Selected the proper one, it was blank when not working even after installed a new version of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened, not because I hadn't specified a location to Xcode, but because I was using Xcode 8.

It's a weird behaviour, because in my case `/usr/bin/xcrun` existed all right, but it was not included in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`. In previous versions of Xcode, that directory contained `xcrun`, but not in Xcode 8, at least not on my version of Mac OS X.

I tried creating a symbolic link there, pointing to `/usr/bin/xcrun`, but it didn't solve the problem.

The only solution I found was to change the code that was triggering the error, by replacing `/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun` with `/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild`.

I think it is a pretty safe thing to do, since this command aims at checking that Xcode is correctly installed is set up, thus the new command does the job. Reassuringly, that' what Qtbase did: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?h=wip/nacl